# Finding the inverse of functions

Tags: functions, inverse

I have the question " Find an equation for the inverse for the relation $y = -8x + 16$".

I get the answer $f^{-1}(x) = (x-16)/-8$.

Is this final answer correct ?

Comment: Yes, but I'd write it $\dfrac{16-X}8$, or $2-\dfrac X8$.

Comment: The result is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are correct. You may want to remove the minus sign:
$$
f^{-1}(x)=\frac{16-x}{8}.
$$